# MYSQL Query suddenly no longer works

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have the following MySQL that fecthes data from several tables:

```
SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts
    LEFT JOIN taxi ON ($wpdb->posts.ID = taxi.taxiID)
    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON ($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id)
    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON ($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
    WHERE $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish' 
    AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'post' 
    AND $wpdb->posts.post_date < NOW()+INTERVAL 1 DAY 
    AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'category' 
    AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id IN(3)
    AND taxi.taxiID IS NULL
    AND ($wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'EndDate' AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value > DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 HOUR))
```

As of yesterday, the query is NOT returning any results but here's the kicker: it used to return results all the time for two weeks!

After a lot of trial and error, I've narrowed the problem down to this one line:

```
AND taxi.taxiID IS NULL
```

That line is supposed to cause the results to filter to show only those posts that don't have a record in the taxi table.

Can anyone help me figure out how to solve the problem?

Comment: Why did someone downrate this? It is a legitimate question! Removing that line of code will display results, but the results will not have been filtered. Applying that filter kills all results on the site, but NOT in PHP my admin. The question is, why?

Comment: Is your query in a HEREDOC? I'm missing a lot of context in this code.

Comment: I don't even know what HEREDOC is. It is simply that this MySQL query worked before and now doesn't. I never touched the query. I don't understand why it works on the server but not in the context of the php file..

Comment: there are PHP variables in the query above.  which means it is not (necessarily) exactly the same as what you are running in mysqlAdmin.  please echo the output of the above code, and provide it for us.

Comment: If I hardcode the variables, the same problem occurs. The output is quite simply the records stored in my database. However, NOTHING gets displayed on the website hence nothing to show you guys...

Comment: I've updated my problem - the problem was in fact a different line of code. Removing that line yields results but using that line I have no results. So the question is, what's wrong with that line of code?

Answer (score 0):

If this query is in a heredoc, make your interpolation explicit. http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

```
$query = <<<HERE
SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->posts}
    LEFT JOIN userContests ON ({$wpdb->posts}.ID = taxi.taxiID)
    LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->term_relationships} ON ({$wpdb->posts}.ID = {$wpdb->term_relationships}.object_id)
    LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->term_taxonomy} ON ({$wpdb->term_relationships}.term_taxonomy_id = {$wpdb->term_taxonomy}.term_taxonomy_id)
    WHERE {$wpdb->posts}.post_status = 'publish' 
    AND {$wpdb->posts}.post_type = 'post' 
    AND {$wpdb->posts}.post_date < NOW()+INTERVAL 1 DAY 
    AND {$wpdb->term_taxonomy}.taxonomy = 'category' 
    AND {$wpdb->term_taxonomy}.term_id IN(3)
    AND ({$wpdb->postmeta}.meta_key = 'EndDate' AND {$wpdb->postmeta}.meta_value > DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 HOUR))
HERE
```

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that your PHP script timeout is occurring?
Remember that just b/c the SQL query doesnt change, doesnt mean the data doesnt either. If the query is too complex or there is too much data it could definitly cause a timeout. This would explain why it works in phpmyadmin, but not your PHP script. phpmyadmin adds a LIMIT clause that allows the mysql server to only return a fraction of results, and therefore rarely timing out.

Try setting the max_execution_time to something higher.

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); //300 seconds = 5 minutes
```